# How to prevent location information from any dialing call

Tags: phone, smartphone

Assume you receive many unknown calls from unknown numbers regularly. 
You would like to prevent the callers to receive any pieces of information from you. 
How can you do this?

Your number is connected to What'sUp -service. This can be leaking your location too.

Your location data is transferred to the caller, once you answer normally. 
**How can you prevent your location data from being transferred to the caller?**

Comment: How is your location data being transferred to the caller?

Comment: I think you need to explain some of your assumptions in your question. What technology is used for the calls? Cell? Skype? How do you know that your location data is sent? Is being connected to What's Up a requirement to answer the question?